# Can I use this media query together @media(prefers-color-scheme:dark) {} and @media (max-width: 425px){}

Tags: css

Can I use  this  media query together 
**@media(prefers-color-scheme:dark) {}** and **@media (max-width: 425px){}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) and (max-width: 425px) { ... }
```